# Получить информацию об организации

Tags: java, c#, c++, c

Необходимо получить информацию об организации (на территории РФ)- ОГРН, КПП, ОКПО и т.д., как это делают такие приложения как 1С, Контур, СБИС и др.. Собственно это информация находится в общем доступе, как бесплатный вариант - отправить запрос на сайт, который специализируется на данной теме, далее "распарсить" ответ, но такие костыли не хотелось бы изобретать. Наверняка существует куча `API` по взаимодействию с базами. Собственно вопрос - какими API пользоваться, есть ли бесплатные варианты. Язык программирования предпочтительно любой из `c`.

Comment: У вас запрос не целостный. API не привязаны к конкретным языкам, так что искать API под язык бессмысленно. Либо вы просите подсказать подходящие API, либо ,если они у вас есть, просите помочь с реализацией, когда столкнетесь с проблемой. Сейчас ваш вопрос выглядит примерно так: "я не знаю как это сделать и где брать информацию, дайте код чтоб делал что надо и было бесплатно". Переоформите вопрос или он будет закрыт

Comment: "отправить запрос на сайт, который специализируется на данной теме, далее "распарсить" ответ" - разве специальные API не именно это и делают, т.е. отправляют запрос в какую-то бд и парсят?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому интересно:
нашел несколько платных сервисов:

1. самый популярный с [налог ру](https://www.nalog.ru/rn77/service/egrip2/), но там не доступны в полной мере информация из ЕГРИП и ЕГРЮЛ.
2. далее очень удобный сервис [dadata](https://dadata.ru/api/suggest/) поддерживает много языков, в том числе `с#`, но можно вытащить только базовые сведения.
3. самая полная информация - через сбербанк `API`, но стоит не дешево.

Бесплатного варианта пока не нашел.

Так же нашел вариант - услуги предоставляет контур диадок, с сопутствующими SDK на `с++` и на `java` - но стоимость впечатляет.

Comment: На то и рассчитано. Вы можете узнать только публичные данные. На другие у вас спросят зачем и почему и заставят подписать кучу бумаг.

Comment: @Aziz Umarov мне больше и не нужно, только то, что в общем доступе - и то все платно сделали

Comment: Значит надо покупать подписку с бесплатными проблем будет больше.

Comment: [API ФНС](https://api-fns.ru/index) - 100 запросов за 8 часов, обрабатывают бесплатно

Comment: @Barmaley Red Star спс большое!!! Но я нашел еще круче, оказывается на сервиче dadata есть бесплатный тариф на 10 000 запросов, плюс есть возможность к доступу других баз, например - определить банк по БИК